# subject-based philosophical book request

Tags: reference-request

Is there a subject-based philosophical book? 
one book which discusses in each chapter a philosophical subject such as ethics, nature of world, ...

Comment: By 'subject-based' do you mean one which discusses a variety of philosophical subjects? If so, the Norton Introduction to Philosophy is one such text, although there are plenty others out there.

Comment: Yes, I mean a book with a variety of subjects

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion: The Norton Introduction to Philosophy

Comment: I suspect there are many, but one I have that I haven't read is Thomas Cathcart and Daniel Klein's "Plato and a Platypus Walk into a Bar..."  There are ten chapters each on a different subject.

Answer (score 1):

A few out of many - these may help :

Jon Nuttall, An Introduction to Philosophy (Paperback)
ISBN 10: 0745616631 / ISBN 13: 9780745616636
Published by Polity Press, United Kingdom, 2002

Ronald H. Nash, Life s Ultimate Questions: An Introduction to Philosophy
ISBN 10: 0310514924 / ISBN 13: 9780310514923
Published by ZONDERVAN, United States, 2013

Peter Cave, Philosophy: A Beginner's Guide
ISBN 10: 1851689370 / ISBN 13: 9781851689378
Published by Oneworld Publications, 2012

Roger Scruton, An Intelligent Person's Guide to Philosophy
ISBN 10: 0715627899 / ISBN 13: 9780715627891
Published by Gerald Duckworth and Co Ltd, 1997
[Scruton was stuck with this title because of the series of which his book was a part.

Philosophy 1: A Guide Through the Subject: A Guide Through the Subject Vol 1
ISBN 10: 0198752431 / ISBN 13: 9780198752431
Published by OUP Oxford, 1998

Philosophy 2: Further through the Subject 
ISBN 10: 0198751788 / ISBN 13: 9780198751786
Published by Oxford University Press, USA, 1999

Jenny Teichman, Katherine C. Evans, Philosophy: A Beginner's Guide
ISBN 10: 063121321X / ISBN 13: 9780631213215
Published by Wiley-Blackwell, 1999

Recommendations : Teichman & Evans is probable the most accessible. Cave next in accessibility, then Nuttall, Nash, Scruton (pretty well equal). Philosophy 1 & 2 cover all the main areas of philosophy in considerable detail : big books, however, and best useful for reference rather than a read right through.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions are:

[The Norton Introduction to Philosophy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22760453-the-norton-introduction-to-philosophy) by [possibleworld](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/13745/possibleworld)

[Plato and a Platypus Walk Into a Bar: Understanding Philosophy Through Jokes](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/180995.Plato_and_a_Platypus_Walk_Into_a_Bar) by [Frank Hubeny](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/29944/frank-hubeny)